# MySQL order by convert varchar as unsigned and sort "0" to the last

Tags: mysql, sorting, casting

In MySQL, I need to ORDER BY CAST(varchar AS unsigned), however, I also need to order the "0" as in the end. Is there any possible way I can do that?
For example:

```
"1"
"10"
"0"
"2"
```

the result should be

```
"1"
"2"
"10"
"0"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ORDER BY col = '0', CAST(col AS unsigned)
```

`col = '0'` will be `0` if it's not zero, `1` if it is, so it will order all the non-zero values first. Then it will sort numerically within those two groups.

Comment: That's the correct answer for this case. My fault, I asked the wrong answer.